# Flow generics incompatible types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm running into flow type errors with generic props in a React component.

Props are generic, and have a property with an array of the generic type.
Then in the Component's methods that use the array data i run into errors with types being incompatible.

Why would the class method `inner()` parameter `data: T[]` be incompatible with `Props<T>.data` when `T` is the same type?

My React component type is `class MyComponent<T> extends React.Component<Props<T>>`

Simplified version of the problem without React:

```
/* @flow */

type Props<ItemType> = {
  data: ItemType[],
  getValue: ItemType => string
}

class B<T> {
  props: Props<T>;

  // comment out props typedef and it works
  constructor(props: Props<T>) {
    this.props = props;
    this.inner(this.props.data);
  }

  inner = (data: T[]) => data.map(i => this.props.getValue(i))
}

---
gives the following type error:

14:     this.inner(this.props.data);
                   ^ Cannot call `this.inner` with `this.props.data` bound to `data` because `T` [1] is incompatible with `T` [2] in array element.
References:
4:   data: ItemType[],
           ^ [1]
17:   inner = (data: T[]) => data.map(i => this.props.getValue(i))
                     ^ [2]
```

[same code in flow repl](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKATnDgM4A8AkhngLYAqueAfGALxgDeqYYAEwCGGIQC4wtBs3wBtALoAaPmADmeDADUhMAK54JUpi07tyGYgEsAdqtQBfdAGMYQ8uTAAhSo3a9+OKQUEiRkVL4A3CoqwMBgTnD09HjWGGBwummBYWDY+AJ4UGBC1gJglmkIcMQA1uQqCdbmxLpOGNUAFNnBREHhrACUPCr8GAAWluQAdN0eXLNR-KMT0zbWeMQd45MzfVPCogOLYI5LZ0sqaxucYB0H4mCMCkMc7PdT9EI4HZamuSu7MJTdRaHT6H4DAYOVBAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be [a bug in Class Fields](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4743)

If you convert inner to

```
inner(data: T[]) {
  return data.map(i => this.props.getValue(i))
}
```

It should work.

If you specifically require inner to be bound to `this`, then remember in your constructor to do: (except that [doesn't work](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5193))

```
this.inner = this.inner.bind(this)
```

Comment: That's it - thank you! didn't even occur to me that this could be a bug in flow, and kind of hard to find the search terms for the problem